# How do I delete posts?

Tags: support

I just gave an answer but it was a question. How can I delete it?

Comment: Your "answer" probably was already deleted by the community as "Not an answer". As of current, your only post other than this is [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123158/connecting-with-pc-via-usb/123199#123199).

Answer (score 8):

There should be a "delete" link beneath the body of your post:

> [image]